# When is x(1/x) = 1 in floating point arithmetic?

Tags: floating-point, ieee-754

I know that in floating point arithmetic, x(1/x) might not be exactly 1 due to rounding error. The smallest positive integer for which this happens should be x=49.

I thought x(1/x) would be exactly 1 if 1/x can be expressed exactly in floating point arithmetic, but my professor said it is actually more nuanced than that and pointed out 5 as an example. I just cannot figure out what other reasons could there be. Can someone give me a hint? Thanks in advance!

Comment: there's not a single floating-point type and format. If you want IEEE-754 then tag it explicitly and even IEEE-754 has many formats which will have different results

Comment: Ok, I meant the standard IEEE-754 double precision.

Comment: Yes, if 1/x can be exactly represented then x*(1/x) will be exactly 1.0.  But the converse is not true -- even if 1/x cannot be exactly represented, x*(1/x) might still end up rounding to 1.0.  That's what happens with numbers like 5.

Comment: There is a rounding error (possibly zero) when `1/x` is computed. And there is another rounding error when the result of that is multiplied by `x`. Sometimes the roundings happen to be in opposite directions and they cancel each other out. Sometimes they do not.

Comment: Not a full answer: You can reduce the problem to cases `1<=x<2` (ignoring sub-normals and non-finite cases). Then check how much rounding error `1/x` can have at most, calculate  `(1/x+error)*x = 1 + error*x` and see when `error * x` can be bigger than `epsilon`. Not sure if you can trivially determine which `x` will actually cause an error, but you can rule out quite a few, e.g., I think `x<1.5` should always round back to exactly 1.

Comment: Actually, my assumption is not true. E.g., `x=561/512` is a counter example.

Comment: @EricPostpischil But isn't 1.0/5 = 0.2 exactly? I see the possibility that the errors cancel each other, but is this the case for 5, for example?

Comment: @InsultedByMathematics `1.0/5 = 0.2` --> No.  All finite binary IEEE-754 numbers are some finite integer times a limited power of 2.  0.2 is not _exactly_ expressible as a common [`double`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I thought x(1/x) would be exactly 1 if 1/x can be expressed exactly in floating point arithmetic,

True, when "1/x can be expressed exactly" as the mathematical equivalent.

> but my professor said it is actually more nuanced than that and pointed out 5 as an example.

5 does not meet the criteria of "if 1/x can be expressed exactly" as 1.0/5.0 is not *exactly* 0.2 with common [double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).  Try:

```
printf("%.*g\n", DBL_DECIMAL_DIG, 1.0/5.0);
```

> might not be exactly 1 due to rounding error.

True.  There also exist range concerns as `1.0/DBL_TRUE_MIN` is usually infinity.
0.0, Infinity, NAN are the other [usually suspects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtSmfws0_To).

> ... what other reasons ...

"There is a rounding error (possibly zero) when 1/x is computed. And there is another rounding error when the result of that is multiplied by x. Sometimes the roundings happen to be in opposite directions and they
cancel each other out. Sometimes they do not."  [@Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77085802/when-is-x1-x-1-in-floating-point-arithmetic#comment135899193_77085802)

Comment: It would be interesting to answer in which proportion it does cancel depending on rounding mode - which can be counted by direct experiments in case of single precision float...